# Capacity of fundamental types across different platforms

Tags: c++, types

I know that `sizeof(type)` will return different values, depending on the platform and the compiler.

However, I know that whenever talking about `ints (int32)` it is said that it can be one of 2^32 values.

If I'm on a platform where `int32` is 8 bytes, it's theoretical maximum is 2^64. Can it really store that much data, or does it always store 4 bytes and use 4 bytes for padding?

The question really is, while I know that sizes of types will differ, I want to know whether asking for max_int on various platform will be constant or will it give me the value according to the type size.

Particularly when dealing with files. If I write `int32` to file, will it always store 4 bytes, or will it depend?

EDIT:
Given all the comments and the fact that I'm trying to create an equivalent of C# BinaryReader, I think that using fixed size type is the best choice, since it would delegate all this to whoever uses it (making it more flexible). Right?

Comment: Are you talking about `int32_t` from the C++11 standard ([fixed width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)) or the "normal" `int` type? Because `int32_t` is guaranteed to be exactly 32bits, while the "normal" `int` type is only guaranteed to be at least 16bits

Comment: Normal int. I want to write a class in C++ that will mimic C# BinaryReader.

Comment: Also [`INT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) or [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) will return the maximum size of an `int` depending on how the compiler implements it.

Comment: Normal int does not have to be 32 bits, but is specified to be 32 bits on pretty much every major desktop system. Does that difference matter to you?

Comment: why would a int that uses only 4 bytes occupy 4 more bytes for padding? Padding happens only if you have a `struct { sometypeOfsize4 x; sometypeOfsize8 y;};` but for an integral type it would be rather wasteful to have 4 padding bytes at the end, no?

Comment: @tobi303: Because the `int` type is actually a fixed-point 32.32 number in hardware, just with the fractional point set to 0? And that's _less_ weird than the old Cray systems where `int`'s were 23 bits, implemented on top of 32 bits floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**std::int32_t** has always a size of 32bit (usually 4 bytes).

The size of **int** can vary and depends on the platform you compile for, but at least 16 bit (usually 2 bytes).

You can check the max value of your type in C++:

```
#include <limits>

std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max()
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

Comment: Technically the standard specifies sizes in bits, not bytes. A byte does not have to be 8 bits (though that is the most common size)

Comment: Indeed, but on a 16 bits DSP `sizeof(std::int32_t)==2`. And on that system, `sizeof(int)==1` is also legal. The size of int has to be at least two _octets_, but the C++ Standard rarely uses octets.

Comment: `int` is usually 4 octects on modern PCs and 2 octects on smaller boards.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think using bits instead of bytes should require much adaptation since most languages I'm familiar with define the size of their (fundamental/primitive/integral) data types in bits. Also "calculating" the size of e.g.: `int32_t` in bytes is more "work" than just talking about it in bits. (Maybe you meant to reply to MSalters?)

Comment: @Quentin You are misquoting me. People who program _exotic DSP:s_ in C++ are most likely incompetent. Arguably, such DSP:s (such as the oddball TI 16 bit DSP:s) shouldn't even be programmed in C, but in assembler. As for "embedded JS", I barely even know what that is. Perhaps you are confusing embedded systems programming with "stuff that is embedded in web sites"... in which case you should probably stop commenting on this topic now.

Comment: @Lundin fair enough, I did miss "exotic". About JS on embedded devices... You wish I were kiddding, [but I'm not](http://embeddednodejs.com/chapters.html) -- people are actually experimenting with JS on microcontrollers today ;)

Comment: @Quentin Something that executes on top of something, which executes on top of something is hardly embedded systems programming, it is a PC without a screen.. But well yeah, "IoT" is brining out the worst of both worlds: now we have web programmers who don't know jack about hardware coding hardware-related programs, and embedded programmers who don't know jack about internet security coding web interfaces. As long as the result is a washing machine that is crashing, moving by itself and performing ddos attacks on random bystanders, everyone is happy, right. Didn't want it to do laundry anyway.